# viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios

мне нужно что бы надпись была на 15 пикселей от левого края, как это можно реализовать?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (section == 2) {
    UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    sectionHeader.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-UltraLight" size:13];
    sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:210.0/255.0  green:185.0/255.0  blue:165.0/255.0  alpha:1];
    sectionHeader.textAlignment = [CGPointMake(15, 500) ];
    sectionHeader.text = @"INFORMATION & SUPPORT";

    return sectionHeader;
}
return nil;
```

}

Comment: сделать sectionHeader `UIView` положить `UILabel` на него в нужном месте

Comment: вы имеете ввиду, что

    UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] init];

нужно сделать 

    UIView *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] init];

и в xib файле поместить label?

Comment: `viewForHeaderInSection` возвращает `UIView`. Вы возвращаете `UILabel`, что в целом нормально - поскольку это сабкласс `UIView`, но то, что вы хотите сделать проще сделать через `UIView` с `UILabel` на нем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо сделать `UIView` и поставить `UILabel` на него сверху.

```
UIView *headerContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];
headerContainer.frame = //здесь какой вам надо размер заголовка
UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] init];
sectionHeader.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-UltraLight" size:13];
sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:210.0/255.0  green:185.0/255.0  blue:165.0/255.0  alpha:1];

CGRect frame = headerContainer.frame;
frame.origin.x += 15;
frame.size.width -= 15;
sectionHeader.frame = frame;

sectionHeader.text = @"INFORMATION & SUPPORT";
[headerContainer.view addSubview:sectionHeader];

return headerContainer;
```

Можно то же самое делать в xib.